# Sunspot Searchable :as, :using, :multiple

Tags: sunspot-solr

Does anyone know the documentation URL for the :as, :using, and :multiple symbols in Sunspot's searchable block? I found it before, now I cannot find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anything with the symbol :as. I found :using and :multiple at: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Setting-up-classes-for-search-and-indexing

Edit:
Found some info on the :as at https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot/lib/sunspot/field.rb